# 位置情報内に未来の時刻が入る

Tags: android, gps

2015年の5月に、以下のAPIを使用して取得した位置情報の中に、2095年9月の日時が入るという事象が発生しました。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()

APIによって未来の時刻が取得されるなど、過去事例はありますでしょうか。